# Customize Hadoop Mapper

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, pdfbox

The Larger purpose of what I have to develop is as follows :-

a) A dashboard, where apart from other features, users can upload documents (.pdf,.txt,.doc). All these documents go to a particular directory.

b) The users can also query all the documents tagged with a particular keyword.

Now, I wish to use `Hadoop` to perform the tagging of documents.I aim to implement this by using a dictionary of selected words.Now a `.txt` (or maybe a `.doc` file as well) would be easy to process. However, from my understanding a `.pdf` file cannot be directly processed. I have learnt how to use `Apache PDFBox`. However I am not able to integrate these two, i.e. Hadoop and PDFBox. What I want to do is that my Map-Reduce Program, recieves as input the corpus of .txt/.pdf/.doc files, and before the functioning of Map starts, performes this conversion of `pdf to txt`.

How do I go about it?? Am I thinking in the right direction?? Please Help.

Comment: I'm not sure where Hadoop would come into play here, but if you're aiming to index and query a corpus of documents maybe you're looking for [Apache Lucene/Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have million or billion of document, and you want to classify them, Whether it is `pdf, txt, doc and so on...`But your actual problem is how to use `Apache PDFBox` in `Mapper`, Right Here is link How to load user Library `hadoop`: [LINK](http://rajdipsinhsolanki.blogspot.in/2013/06/hadoop-load-third-party-libraries.html)